# Mobile badge and tag links have inconsistent active/hover state

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The mobile stylesheet defines the following styles for `a:hover, a:active`:

```
a:hover, a:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

This overrides the border set on `.badge` and `.badge-tag` when the badge link is considered active or hovered, which happens during page transition after you tap the link, as well as if you then press back (on iOS, at least). Tag links have a similar problem.

Please give the links back their borders when they're active, so I don't have to keep drawing them on:

[image: tag badge link with missing border]

Comment: -1 for the FHC being black and not red ...

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2245` on meta and `rev 1606` on the network).